# Why can't we see all the rows of a large dataframe in R? Why does R omit most of the rows as an o/p while we try to see the full dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe

The data-set has about 900 rows but R shows only 120 rows and omits the rest

[ reached 'max' / getOption("max.print") -- omitted 787 rows ]

Comment: What is the output of `getOption("max.print")`? I would guess approx. 120 * the number of columns in your data frame. Check out `help("getOption")`. You'll also see there the function `options()`. You can change this behavior via, e.g., `options(max.print = 1000 * ncol(dfx))`, where you replace `dfx` with the name of your data frame, which should let you print the whole data frame

Comment: It might be more convenient to use `View(DF)` where `DF` is your data.frame.

Comment: View() works well enough. Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
options(max.print=1000)
```

This will show all the rows for your dataframe. Also look at `?options` for more detials.